# How to fix 'Unable to login as the service principal' exception caused due to 'Unable to obtain password from user' for Tomcat Windows Authentication?

Tags: jakarta-ee, windows-authentication, kerberos, tomcat8, spnego

I am trying to implement windows authentication for Tomcat8.0 webapps using its inbuilt support. And I'm getting the following exception in the **TOMCAT_HOME\logs\tomcat8-stderr.2017-03-17.log** file :-

```
17-Mar-2017 10:59:39.367 FINE [http-nio-8080-exec-6] org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke Security checking request GET /testad/
17-Mar-2017 10:59:39.367 FINE [http-nio-8080-exec-6] org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase.findSecurityConstraints   Checking constraint 'SecurityConstraint[Common Area]' against GET /index.jsp --> true
17-Mar-2017 10:59:39.367 FINE [http-nio-8080-exec-6] org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase.findSecurityConstraints   Checking constraint 'SecurityConstraint[Common Area]' against GET /index.jsp --> true
17-Mar-2017 10:59:39.367 FINE [http-nio-8080-exec-6] org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke  Calling hasUserDataPermission()
17-Mar-2017 10:59:39.367 FINE [http-nio-8080-exec-6] org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase.hasUserDataPermission   User data constraint has no restrictions
17-Mar-2017 10:59:39.367 FINE [http-nio-8080-exec-6] org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke  Calling authenticate()
17-Mar-2017 10:59:39.383 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-6] org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SpnegoAuthenticator.doAuthenticate Unable to login as the service principal
 javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Unable to obtain password from user

    at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.promptForPass(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.attemptAuthentication(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.login(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(Unknown Source)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SpnegoAuthenticator.doAuthenticate(SpnegoAuthenticator.java:197)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:556)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:798)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1434)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

17-Mar-2017 10:59:39.383 FINE [http-nio-8080-exec-6] org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke  Failed authenticate() test
```

Following are my environment details:-

1. Windows Server 2012 (FQDN: **dev.devdevelopment.com**) for AD
2. Windows 7 machine (FQDN: **windows7devpc.devdevelopment.com**) for Apache Tomcat 8.5.11 with Java 1.8.0_31(64 Bit)
3. Windows XP machine as client (Firefox browser)
4. AD Domain Name : devdevelopment.com

I have a domain user **devtomcat** to which the following SPNs are mapped:-

[image]

I have another domain user **devuser** that is a member of a group named **tc-webapp-users** which is inturn within an OU named **tomcat-ou**. This user is used to access the webapp from the windows xp machine.

[image]

Following is my tomcat's **server.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />

  <GlobalNamingResources/>

  <Service name="Catalina">
    <Connector port="8080" maxSavePostSize="2097152" URIEncoding="UTF-8" maxHttpHeaderSize="65536"/>
    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
        <Host name="localhost" appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
            <Context docBase="testad" path="/testad">
                <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm"
                        connectionURL="ldap://dev.devdevelopment.com:389"
                        userSubtree="true"
                        userBase="CN=Users,DC=devdevelopment,DC=com"
                        userSearch="(sAMAccountName={0})"
                        userRoleName="memberOf"
                        roleBase="CN=tc-webapp-users,OU=tomcat-ou,DC=devdevelopment,DC=com"
                        roleName="cn"
                        roleSearch="(member={0})"
                        roleSubtree="true"
                        roleNested="true"/>
                <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SpnegoAuthenticator" storeDelegatedCredential="true"/>
            </Context>
        </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

Following is the webapp's **web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Common Area</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
            <http-method>GET</http-method>
            <http-method>POST</http-method>
            <http-method>PUT</http-method>
            <http-method>HEAD</http-method>
            <http-method>TRACE</http-method>
            <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
            <http-method>OPTIONS</http-method>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>tc-webapp-users</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
        <user-data-constraint>
            <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

    <login-config>
        <auth-method>SPNEGO</auth-method>
    </login-config>

    <security-role>
        <description>TC-WebApp-Roles</description>
        <role-name>tc-webapp-users</role-name>
    </security-role>
</web-app>
```

Following is the content of **krb5.ini** file which is placed under **C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\conf** directory :-

```
[libdefaults]
default_realm=DEVDEVELOPMENT.COM
default_keytab_name=“C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 8.5/conf/tomcat.keytab"
default_tkt_enctypes=rc4-hmac,aes256-cts-hmac-shal-96,aes128-cts-hmac-shal-96
default_tgs_enctypes=rc4-hmac,aes256-cts-hmac-shal-96,aes128-cts-hmac-shal-96
permitted_enctypes=rc4-hmac,aes256-cts-hmac-shal-96,aes128-cts-hmac-shal-96
udp_preference_limit=1
forwardable=true

[realms]
DEVDEVELOPMENT.COM={
    kdc=dev.devdevelopment.com
}

[domain_realm]
devdevelopment.com=DEVDEVELOPMENT.COM
.devdevelopment.com=DEVDEVELOPMENT.COM
```

Following is the content of **jaas.conf** file which is placed under **C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\conf** directory :-

```
com.sun.security.jgss.krb5.accept {
    com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
    doNotPrompt=true
    principal="HTTP/windows7devpc.devdevelopment.com@DEVDEVELOPMENT.COM"
    keyTab="C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\conf\tomcat.keytab"
    storeKey=true
    useKeyTab=true
    useTicketCache=true
    isInitiator=true
    refreshKrb5Config=true
    moduleBanner=true
    storePass=true;
};

com.sun.security.jgss.krb5.initiate {
    com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
    doNotPrompt=true
    principal="HTTP/windows7devpc.devdevelopment.com@DEVDEVELOPMENT.COM"
    keyTab="C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\conf\tomcat.keytab"
    storeKey=true
    useKeyTab=true
    useTicketCache=true
    isInitiator=true
    refreshKrb5Config=true
    moduleBanner=true
    storePass=true
    debug=true;
};
```

Following is the diagnostic output of the JDK's **klist** command (run on the Tomcat machine):-

```
c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\bin>klist -e -k -t "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\conf\tomcat.keytab"

Key tab: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\conf\tomcat.keytab, 1 entry found.

[1] Service principal: HTTP/windows7devpc.devdevelopment.com@DEVDEVELOPMENT.COM
         KVNO: 12
         Key type: 18
         Time stamp: Jan 01, 1970 05:30:00
```

Following is the diagnostic output of the JDK's **kinit** command (run on the Tomcat machine) in debug mode :-

```
c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\bin>kinit -J-Dsun.security.krb5.debug=true -k -t "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\conf\tomcat.keytab" HTTP/windows7devpc.devdevelopment.com@DEVDEVELOPMENT.COM
>>>KinitOptions cache name is C:\Users\devtomcat\krb5cc_devtomcat
Principal is HTTP/windows7devpc.devdevelopment.com@DEVDEVELOPMENT.COM
>>> Kinit using keytab
>>> Kinit keytab file name: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\conf\tomcat.keytab
Java config name: null
LSA: Found Ticket
LSA: Made NewWeakGlobalRef
LSA: Found PrincipalName
LSA: Made NewWeakGlobalRef
LSA: Found DerValue
LSA: Made NewWeakGlobalRef
LSA: Found EncryptionKey
LSA: Made NewWeakGlobalRef
LSA: Found TicketFlags
LSA: Made NewWeakGlobalRef
LSA: Found KerberosTime
LSA: Made NewWeakGlobalRef
LSA: Found String
LSA: Made NewWeakGlobalRef
LSA: Found DerValue constructor
LSA: Found Ticket constructor
LSA: Found PrincipalName constructor
LSA: Found EncryptionKey constructor
LSA: Found TicketFlags constructor
LSA: Found KerberosTime constructor
LSA: Finished OnLoad processing
Native config name: C:\Windows\krb5.ini
>>> Kinit realm name is DEVDEVELOPMENT.COM
>>> Creating KrbAsReq
>>> KrbKdcReq local addresses for windows7devpc are:

        windows7devpc/192.168.1.229
IPv4 address

        windows7devpc/fe80:0:0:0:80f2:1a68:c0f0:710%11
IPv6 address
>>> KdcAccessibility: reset
>>> KeyTabInputStream, readName(): DEVDEVELOPMENT.COM
>>> KeyTabInputStream, readName(): HTTP
>>> KeyTabInputStream, readName(): windows7devpc.devdevelopment.com
>>> KeyTab: load() entry length: 107; type: 18
Looking for keys for: HTTP/windows7devpc.devdevelopment.com@DEVDEVELOPMENT.COM
Added key: 18version: 12
Using builtin default etypes for default_tkt_enctypes
default etypes for default_tkt_enctypes: 18 17 16 23.
>>> KrbAsReq creating message
getKDCFromDNS using UDP
>>> KrbKdcReq send: kdc=dev.devdevelopment.com. UDP:88, timeout=30000, number of retries =3, #bytes=227
>>> KDCCommunication: kdc=dev.devdevelopment.com. UDP:88, timeout=30000,Attempt =1, #bytes=227
>>> KrbKdcReq send: #bytes read=227
>>>Pre-Authentication Data:
         PA-DATA type = 19
         PA-ETYPE-INFO2 etype = 18, salt = DEVDEVELOPMENT.COMHTTPwindows7devpc.devdevelopment.com, s2kparams = null

>>>Pre-Authentication Data:
         PA-DATA type = 2
         PA-ENC-TIMESTAMP
>>>Pre-Authentication Data:
         PA-DATA type = 16

>>>Pre-Authentication Data:
         PA-DATA type = 15

>>> KdcAccessibility: remove dev.devdevelopment.com.:88
>>> KDCRep: init() encoding tag is 126 req type is 11
>>>KRBError:
         sTime is Thu Mar 16 22:50:19 IST 2017 1489684819000
         suSec is 759798
         error code is 25
         error Message is Additional pre-authentication required
         sname is krbtgt/DEVDEVELOPMENT.COM@DEVDEVELOPMENT.COM
         eData provided.
         msgType is 30
>>>Pre-Authentication Data:
         PA-DATA type = 19
         PA-ETYPE-INFO2 etype = 18, salt = DEVDEVELOPMENT.COMHTTPwindows7devpc.devdevelopment.com, s2kparams = null

>>>Pre-Authentication Data:
         PA-DATA type = 2
         PA-ENC-TIMESTAMP
>>>Pre-Authentication Data:
         PA-DATA type = 16

>>>Pre-Authentication Data:
         PA-DATA type = 15

KrbAsReqBuilder: PREAUTH FAILED/REQ, re-send AS-REQ
Using builtin default etypes for default_tkt_enctypes
default etypes for default_tkt_enctypes: 18 17 16 23.
Looking for keys for: HTTP/windows7devpc.devdevelopment.com@DEVDEVELOPMENT.COM
Added key: 18version: 12
Looking for keys for: HTTP/windows7devpc.devdevelopment.com@DEVDEVELOPMENT.COM
Added key: 18version: 12
Using builtin default etypes for default_tkt_enctypes
default etypes for default_tkt_enctypes: 18 17 16 23.
>>> EType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.Aes256CtsHmacSha1EType
>>> KrbAsReq creating message
getKDCFromDNS using UDP
>>> KrbKdcReq send: kdc=dev.devdevelopment.com. UDP:88, timeout=30000, number of retries =3, #bytes=316
>>> KDCCommunication: kdc=dev.devdevelopment.com. UDP:88, timeout=30000,Attempt =1, #bytes=316
>>> KrbKdcReq send: #bytes read=108
>>> KrbKdcReq send: kdc=dev.devdevelopment.com. TCP:88, timeout=30000, number of retries =3, #bytes=316
>>> KDCCommunication: kdc=dev.devdevelopment.com. TCP:88, timeout=30000,Attempt =1, #bytes=316
>>>DEBUG: TCPClient reading 1766 bytes
>>> KrbKdcReq send: #bytes read=1766
>>> KdcAccessibility: remove dev.devdevelopment.com.:88
Looking for keys for: HTTP/windows7devpc.devdevelopment.com@DEVDEVELOPMENT.COM
Added key: 18version: 12
>>> EType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.Aes256CtsHmacSha1EType
>>> KrbAsRep cons in KrbAsReq.getReply HTTP/windows7devpc.devdevelopment.com
New ticket is stored in cache file C:\Users\devtomcat\krb5cc_devtomcat
```

Following are the Java environment variables that are set in **Java** tab of the **Tomcat8 Properties** window :-

[image]

And finally, following are the settings done in the Firefox browser on the Windows xp machine for the domain user **devuser**:-

[image]

[image]

The Wireshark logs in the tomcat machine do not show any entries/activity when the webapp is accessed in windows xp machine. I doubt if the SPNEGO negotiation is being initiated by the tomcat machine.

Should the **krb5.ini** file be placed in **C:\Windows** directory? Also, does the spaces in the keytab file path matter?

I have followed the instructions mentioned [here](https://dzone.com/articles/do-not-publish-configuring-tomcat-single-sign-on-w). Where & what am I doing wrong / missing something?

Comment: This was an extremely well-documented question Shiva.  Great job. Did this question get resolved based on the other question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42998255/why-is-jdk1-8-0u121-unable-to-find-the-kerberos-default-tkt-enctypes-types-krb/43009903#43009903) I recently answered, or is this still a problem?

Comment: Hi THeron. No, this issue is not yet fixed. Though I have changed from the xp client machine to windows 7 machine, still getting the above mentioned exception. I have incorporated your suggestion from the other post too. As I mentioned, wireshark (on the tomcat machine) is not logging any network traffic to or from the KDC server machine.

Comment: This, as well as the other one, was an excellently-worded question.  One of the best I have seen.  This is my favorite area to work in.  I'll need a little bit of time as busy with other stuff, but I'll get back, like with the other one.

Comment: Are you running TomCat as the user that is configured when the keytab file was created, You need to run TomCat as that particular user which has you setspn call. This must have been done at your Domaincontroller end

Answer (score 0):

In `jaas.conf`, include `debug=true`, so it will print the used keytab file name, and other useful infos.

You'll see that keytab file name is handled as an escaped java string, so you should write double backslashes as path separators. Quite tricky issue.